# How to display values starting from the thousands digit

Tags: microsoft-excel, rounding

I have a number of cells, each with a number up to the millions digit.
I have been tasked to round each value to the nearest thousands digit and then make the cells ONLY show the numbers from the thousands digit and upwards.

To give a visual example, basically I would be taking the cells from Photo 1, and make them look like Photo 2 -- rounded up to the nearest thousands digit, and then only showing numbers from the thousands digit and upwards.

Data:
[image: Photo 1]

Aim:
[image: Photo 2]

Answer (score 0):

Look into what you see in the Number or Currency settings in the "Cell format" dialog - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - and copy the format string into the second argument here, e.g:
`=TEXT(A1/1000,"#,##0")`

The temporary division by 1000 gives the "thousands" you are asking for, the second argument formats that number "nicely".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

See [**Format code guidelines**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68): *To display a comma as a thousands separator or **to scale a number by a multiple of 1000**, include a comma (,) in the code for the number format.*

To display **12000** As **12** Use this code **#,**

[image: Help]